# Logged Out problem on cms page save in magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9

Getting following error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:63:"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away";i:1;s:2879:"#0 {main}";s:3:"url";s:135:"/index.php/admin/cms_wysiwyg/directive/___directive/e3tza2luIHVybD0nJ319/key/c85e331ae36188829cb324a6597d12e2/images/banner-static3.png";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't give very much info. I'd recommend you use blackfire to profile your page and make sure you're not using too many database connections on your product page, home page, and listings pages.

Comment: Hi Luke , actually i have created 100 stores on one magento installation, everything was going smooth but suddenly , when we update or save any pages in cms->pages it is going to be session out and after that i have checked var/report/ given  General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away"

Answer (score 0):

It was memory limit issues after increasing it to 512M it worked.

Comment: Could you mark this answer as being the solution, so it's marked as answered. Thanks